# dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android10VectorImpl19reservedVectorImpl1Ev"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-4.4-kitkat

I need help, cause I'm stucked for 2 days from now and i can't find anything.
I bought device: Kcosit V720 on aliexpress and they send me library with it, but it's so hard to get it work correctly.

While I was trying to load library, i had to download libcamera_client.so, because libbarcodereader.so needed it, so i don't know if it is compatible, but now, I'm receiving another error. Any ideas how to fix it ?:

```
2020-06-19 09:29:33.056 7239-7239/com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapplication, PID: 7239
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android10VectorImpl19reservedVectorImpl1Ev" referenced by "/data/app/com.myapplication-1/lib/arm/libbarcodereader.so"...
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
    at com.myapplication.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:12)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing another .so file. Ensure that all .so files are in the same directory.

The following may help to identify referenced .so files:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120015/how-to-find-out-the-dynamic-libraries-executables-loads-when-run

---

Update:

I'm not aware of any android API for this type of hardware. According to https://kcosit.com/kcosit-v720-p1496437.html your device contains most likely a OEM version of the SE4710 barcode scanner, manufactured by Motorola. It seems that there exists an SDK from Motorola but I could only find the corresponding  [documenation](https://help.famoco.com/downloads/SWDecodeAndroid_IG.pdf). It is most likely used as base for SDKs provided by OEM licensors. One of such an SDK is available here: https://developer.zebra.com/community/tools

Maybe you are lucky and you can use this SDK also for your device. If it should
also be compatible with your device you would of course also need to check license of the SDK - I haven't found any info yet. Maybe you are able to find a source for the original SDK from Motorolla or an other SDK from an OEM licensor.

Comment: Thanks, but developer didn't made his job at all. I tried, but can't find those .so files and also i took .apk from SDK which i received by developer, and still same problem.

Comment: Is there any option to create event handler for that scanner ? It's integrated barcode scanner in mobile device

Comment: Yes, they have own sdk, but this is the error I’m getting while running the app.